# No funciona Javascript de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo una pagina con **Spring (JAVA)**, y **Bootstrap 4.0.0**. Al principio había hecho las llamadas a los archivos de **bootstrap** vía link web, y funcionaba todo perfecto. Ahora quiero cambiar esas llamadas para hacerlas utilizando los archivos de forma local, es decir, me baje los archivos de **bootstrap**. Llamo a los **CSS** de forma local y funciona sin problema, pero al momento de llamar a los archivos de **JS** no me funcionan. La sentencias que uso son:

```
<link  href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"/> 
<link  href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"/>" />
```

Cabe aclarar, que las llamadas funcionan, es decir, si veo el **código compilado** e intento entrar al archivo de **JS** mediante la llamada me lleva al archivo, el problema está en que la página no responde como debería con **JS**. Por ejemplo tengo un **alert con dismiss** para cerrarlo y el **botón** de cerrar no funciona, algo que si anda cuando vuelvo a poner la llamada via web.

Comment: Enséñanos un ejemplo del código html / javascript que falla. Mira [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes la carpeta /resources creada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes incluir también **jquery** en tu archivo es por eso que el **javascript** de **Bootstrap** no te funciona correctamente. Siempre debes cargar primero la **librería de jquery** y luego cargas el **".js"** del **bootstrap** así:

```
<link  href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"/>" />
<link  href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"/> 
<link  href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"/>" />
```